# Packet sniffer: IP Header, type of service outputs 0 in C

Tags: c, network-programming, ip, printf

I have following code:

```
struct sniff_ip {
        unsigned char  ip_vhl;                 /* version << 4 | header length >> 2 */
        unsigned char  ip_tos;                 /* type of service */
...
};

...
printf("IP TOS: %d", (unsigned int)ip_hdr->ip_tos);
```

The output of it is 0

But if I change it to:

```
struct sniff_ip {
        unsigned char  ip_vhl;                 /* version << 4 | header length >> 2 */
        u_short  ip_tos;                 /* type of service */
...
};

...
printf("IP TOS: %d", (unsigned int)ip_hdr->ip_tos);
```

The outputs is 10240.

So I have too question, what are possible Type of services outputs and where can I find them? And why does it printfs differently when I change `unsigned char` to `u_short`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The field that used to be called "type of service" is nowadays broken up into two bitfields: the Differentiated Services Codepoint (DSCP) and Explicit Congestion Notification (ECN) fields. For details, please see:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv4#Header

The DSCP field is rarely used, and ECN only infrequently. Both default to zero, which is what you're seeing.

No matter how you parse them, though, these two fields only occupy one byte. By changing your structure definition to treat it as a `u_short`, you are reading additional data beyond the end of the field, in the Total Length field. I'm a little confused why you'd be seeing the data there that you seem to be, though, as `0x28` in the high byte would suggest that you're dealing with a packet that's at least 10 KB!

Comment: Thanks, I know the theory that short is bigger in size, but as I did not program in C I forgot about it. That was really helpfull